# zeromq.node setsockopt throws invalid argument error

Tags: node.js, zeromq

This code...

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var req = zmq.socket('req');
req.setsockopt('hwm', 10); // or req.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_HWM, 10);
```

...throws this error:

```
/Users/.../node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:246
  this._zmq.setsockopt(opts[opt] || opt, val);
            ^
Error: Invalid argument
    at Socket.setsockopt (/Users/.../node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:246:13)
```

*ps. bonus point, is there a way to do something like this `zmq.socket('req', {'hwm': 10})` ?*

> zeromq.node 2.11.1 & zeromq 4.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe once you hit ZMQ 4.0 that `HWM` is an option anymore without specifying whether you mean `SNDHWM`or `RCVHWM`.